# Windows audio/visual notification that a copy event has occurred

Tags: windows, windows-10, copy-paste, copy

I'm not entirely sure why the copy function triggered either via the keyboard or mouse does not register. I would *really* appreciate if there was a way to have some audio or visual queue that a copy event *actually happened*.

I often find myself pasting completely unrelated things and this misbehavior of Windows is so bad I usually press Ctrl+C several times *just to be sure* and even then occasionally it did not register.

This applies equally to both files and text.

Comment: Does this problem happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: But it’s not Windows that’s copying. It’s the application that is focused. That being said, subscribing to clipboard changes is easy in .NET, you could roll your own.